# App Store: is version metadata (screenshots, descriptions,...) lost when canceling a version release?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

**Current scenario**

- App V1 is live on the App Store, V2 is Pending Developer Release, V2.1.
- We would like to avoid releasing V2 and upload a v2.1 with bug fixes and the same metadata as V2 (screenshots, descriptions,...).
- To do so, and since the "Add version" button is disabled, we might have to click "Cancel this release" on v2.1.

**Questions**

1. Will we lose the metadata that were used for v2? Screenshots, descriptions, etc.
2. If so, is there a way to upload v2.1 without losing the metadata of v2 but without releasing it on the App Store?

It's not a big deal if we lose the metadata in any case: we will copy-paste everything. But if there is a simpler/smarted way to do this, interested to know it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We sacrificed ourselves for the greater good and took the risk of canceling the release (after copy-pasting everything just in case): **we did not lose the metadata**.